# OAuth API migration v1 to v2 sdk java

Tags: java, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I'm using Autodesk Forge APIs for developing a web application based on java and recently I've seen that Authentication v1 is deprecated and that I need to migrate to Authentication v2.

I was following the migration guide (https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/migration-guide-oauth2-v1-v2) and the base URL has changed. I'm using Forge Java SDK and in GitHUB (https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-java-client) I couldn’t see any updates in the forge-java-sdk code.

Does anyone know if this update will be available soon or if there’s no longer support with java applications?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: On our roadmap, we were going to expose new JAVA SDK, but not exact time when it would be available. At this moment, you may have to try to edit this forge-api-java-client source code with that tutorial by yourself. Sorry for any inconvenience. your patience and understanding are apppreciated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I modified the source code with the changes explained in the migration guide and it's working fine.